# Blackberry App - Table layout advice

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I'm currently developing a crude, Blackberry app that keeps track of my spending and bank balance.  The app will hold details of the items I have bought and how much they cost.  The item price will then be subtracted from the main, overall bank balance.  All item entries are made manually. 
This is a mock-up of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Above is the main menu. The top item is a banner that displays the bank balance.  The other items are buttons.

The following is view for the items that have been added:

[image]

The table is text apart from the Remove Item field - they are buttons.

I'm looking for advice on how to implement both user interfaces (what classes, use a table or not?)  I've been trying to implement a table to layout the buttons in the main screen and store the item list - I've not had much success!  As I've said at the beginning, this is a crude application - I'm not looking to waste my time trying to implement any fancy GUI, just something functional.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been trying to implement a table to layout the buttons in the main screen

This is an overkill. Just use `VerticalFieldManager` as a buttons (use `ButtonField` for buttons) container.

> .. store the item list

Check this: [How to use Table View layout](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2009/10/how-to-use-table-view-layout/)

Use `LabelField` for text cells.